# Closed Form for Continuant (Determinant Tridiagonal Matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider the particular tridiagonal, $n \times n$ matrix $A$:

A = $\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
a_1&b_2 \\b_1&a_2&b_1\\&b_1&a_2&b_1\\&&&\ddots\\&&&&\ddots\\&&&&b_1&a_2&b_1\\&&&&&b_2&a_1
\end{array}\right)$

where the empty space is zero, then the [continuant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuant_%28mathematics%29/) offers a recursive formula for the determinant, which I believe is given by:

```
|A(n)| = a(1) * |A(n-1)| + b(1)*b(1)*|A(n-2)|  ;  |A(0)| = 1, |A(1)| = a(n)
```

I don't see a closed formula for this anywhere, and I can't figure out how to find one.

If there isn't a closed formula, are there conditions we can set such that there is?

I attempted this by partitioning it into block matrices, but I can't seem to get it to work? I can provide that attempt if it helps.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are there $a_2$'s and $b_2$'s in the matrix? Where are they? Is the matrix symmetric?

Comment: A[0][0] and A[n-1][n-1] are a1; everything else on the main diagonal is a2. The term b2 appears twice; a[0][1], and a[n-2][n-1]; the subdiagonal and superdiagonal are otherwise b1. I can give a formal definition if you want it but it's more confusing than helpful.

Comment: No, that is fine. What made me suspicious is that the title says "Symmetric tridiagonal matrix", but with this definition with those $b_2$'s it is not necessarily symmetric unless $b_1=b_2$.

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I meant to change that when I modified the question; b1 != b2, in general.

Comment: After the first few terms, your coefficients are constant, so you have $A_{k} = a_2A_{k-1} - b_1^2A_{k-2}$. [This recurrence relation can be solved for a closed form solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) up to $A_{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes that's why I suspected that it had a closed form, because the terms repeat so nicely. I can't figure out how to solve the recurrence relation though... For example, one of the Wikipedia methods involves eigenvalues... if I knew how to calculate eigenvalues, then I'd already know the determinant.